# ¿Cómo redirigir a una ruta luego de que la validación del CanActiveFn sea false?

Tags: angular, redirección, angular-router

Mi codigo actual es este.

```
import { CanActivateFn } from '@angular/router';

export const formularioGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const plantillaSeleccionada = sessionStorage.getItem('plantilla');

  if (plantillaSeleccionada) {
    return true;
  } else {
    window.location.href = "/plantillas";
    return false;
  }
};
```

Hago la redirección con `window.location.href = "/plantillas";` pero eso obliga a cargar toda la pagina, en lugar de solo refrescar los componentes por ser una SPA.

Comment: y que has intentado o investigado, hasta donde llegaste??? te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: Lee la documentación https://angular.io/guide/router#specifying-a-relative-route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para redireccionar directamente desde una guarda a otra ruta, lo que tienes que hacer es devolver un objeto `UrlTree` que represente a la nueva ruta. Para ello lo más fácil es usar los métodos `parseUrl` o `createUrlTree` del Router.

En tu caso cuando no haya plantilla, en vez de devolver `false` tendrías que devolver:

```
return inject(Router).parseUrl('/plantillas');
```

o:

```
return inject(Router).createUrlTree(['/plantillas']);
```

slds